# selecting 30 cells from the bottom active text to up excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hello i would like to copy the last 30 cells of my column B.

the below code is copying to right, but i want it to copy only the 30 last cells of the column b

```
Sub test()
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 30)).Copy
End Sub
```

kindly help.
best regards

Comment: any feedback to any of the answers you got ? I'm quite sure one of them helped you, and you should mark it as "Answer"

Comment: Hello it's worked.. thank you soo much. your suggested is well noted too. Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
With Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    Range(.Cells, .Offset(WorksheetFunction.Max(-.Row + 1, -29))).Copy
End With
```

and handle the case there are less than 30 *last* cells

Comment: @h.barry, did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

Find the last row with data in Column B (including empty rows in the middle), and then copy the range (from 29 rows down till last row found) .

**Note**: try not to use `ActiveCell` if you can, instead use fully qualified `Range`.

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B" & LastRow - 29 & ":B" & LastRow).Copy
```

Comment: Completely agreed with Shai. His approach will be far more dynamic, and avoiding Select is very important for making your code dynamic. While the code you (OP) initially posted works, it is not an effective means of tackling the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the future I strongly suggest trying to solve your problem by looking up the arguments for the functions you use. See fixed code below:

```
Sub test()
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(-29, 0)).Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B" & N - 29 & ":B" & N).Copy
End Sub
```